# Approximate unit for a certain C*-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $p$ a projection in $A^{**}$. To prove $p$ is the smallest unit for $B: = \{a\in A; pap=a\}$, suppose $\{u_i\}$ is an approximate unit for $B$. It's easy to see $q: = w^*-\lim u_i$ is a projection. Also $q\leq p$. How can prove $p=q$?

Comment: Please check this argument: If $a\in B$ then $pap=a$ and therefore $pa=pap=a$ and $ap=pap=a$ as well. It means that $p$ is a unit for $B$. It seems that you do not need to use the approximate identity.

Comment: @AliBagheri, But $p \in A^{**}$. By your argument $1\in A^{**}$ is a unit for $B$ too. I need prove $p$ is the smallest unit for $B$.

Comment: Yes the term "the smallest unit" should be also considered. For the second time that I reviewed your problem, I feel your assertion in not true in general!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this assertion holds  if and only if $p$ is an open projection.

**Def.** A projection $p$ in $A^{**}$ is called open if there is an increasing net $\{a_i\}$ of positive elements of the unit ball of $A$ with $p=w^*-\lim a_i$.

**Example.** Let us consider the C*-algebra $A=C[0,1]$. If $p$ is a minimal projection in $A^{**}=C[0,1]^{**}$ then $a=pap$ if and only if $a=0$, since (always) minimal projections in $A^{**}$ are just support of pure states on $A$ and so in this particular case they are just Dirac measures.